# Finding out where my method is getting used?

Tags: php, class

I have a class and I don't know if there are any objects calling this class. Is there a way to list all objects which call a method of a specific class? What I need is the file name and maybe the line number.

Comment: See [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: Install IDE like PhpStorm and search for usage of your class.